# `this` reference gets lost in prototype chain

Tags: javascript

This is quite extensive, but fun and detailed.

I have defined two "classes" as follow, using the standard JavaScript ways of prototypes:

## Source

```
function Source() {
  this._sourceGuid = "";
  this._periodGuid = "";
  this._eventName = "";
  this._eventKind = 0;

  if (arguments.length > 0) {
    if (arguments[0].__proto__ === this.__proto__) {
      this.sourceGuid(arguments[0].sourceGuid());
      this.periodGuid(arguments[0].periodGuid());
      this.eventName(arguments[0].eventName());
      this.eventKind(arguments[0].eventKind());
    } else {
      this.sourceGuid(arguments[0].sourceGuid);
      this.periodGuid(arguments[0].periodGuid);
      this.eventName(arguments[0].eventName);
      this.eventKind(arguments[0].eventKind);
    }
  }
};

Source.prototype.sourceGuid = function (value) {
  if (arguments.length > 0) {
    this._sourceGuid = value
  } else {
    return this._sourceGuid;
  }
};

Source.prototype.periodGuid = function (value) {
  if (arguments.length > 0) {
    this._periodGuid = value
  } else {
    return this._periodGuid;
  }
};

Source.prototype.eventName = function (value) {
  if (arguments.length > 0) {
    this._eventName = value
  } else {
    return this._eventName;
  }
};

Source.prototype.eventKind = function (value) {
  if (arguments.length > 0) {
    this._eventKind = value
  } else {
    return this._eventKind;
  }
};

Source.prototype.toJSON = function() {
  return {
    sourceGuid: this.sourceGuid(),
    periodGuid: this.periodGuid(),
    eventName: this.eventName(),
    eventKind: this._eventKind()
  };
};
```

## AnalogCamerasSource extends Source

```
function AnalogCamerasSource() {

  this.__proto__.apply(this, arguments);

  this._serverGuid = "";
  this._cameraId = 0;
  this._waitingTime = 0;

  if (arguments.length > 0) {
    if (arguments[0].__proto__ === this.__proto__) {
      this.serverGuid(arguments[0].serverGuid());
      this.cameraId(arguments[0].cameraId());
      this.waitingTime(arguments[0].waitingTime());
    } else {
      this.serverGuid(arguments[0].serverGuid);
      this.cameraId(arguments[0].cameraId);
      this.waitingTime(arguments[0].waitingTime);
    }
  }
};

AnalogCamerasSource.prototype = Source;

AnalogCamerasSource.prototype.serverGuid = function (value) {
  if (arguments.length > 0) {
    this._serverGuid = value
  } else {
    return this._serverGuid;
  }
};

AnalogCamerasSource.prototype.cameraId = function (value) {
  if (arguments.length > 0) {
    this._cameraId = value
  } else {
    return this._cameraId;
  }
};

AnalogCamerasSource.prototype.waitingTime = function (value) {
  if (arguments.length > 0) {
    this._waitingTime = value
  } else {
    return this._waitingTime;
  }
};

AnalogCamerasSource.prototype.toJSON = function() {
  var json = this.__proto__.toJSON();

  json.serverGuid = this.serverGuid();
  json.cameraId = this.cameraId();
  json.waitingTime = this.waitingTime();

  return json;
};
```

Now I need an instance of `AnalogCamerasSource`, and I am trying to create it as simply as that:

```
var data = {"sourceGuid":"{05A00E05-F30D-497D-A272-156F135E1486}","periodGuid":"{8A071454-B473-4937-9C54-4899F866D7FA}","eventName":"signal-lost","eventKind":3,"serverGuid":"{9976B57D-486B-4BCA-8432-78D7C8EDB52B}","cameraId":4,"waitingTime":5};

var c = new AnalogCamerasSource(data);
```

Now, the line `this.__proto__.apply(this, arguments);` is responsible for calling the parent's constructor, and it seems it should do it fine, but at the moment it should call a parent's function in the parent's constructor, the following error is thrown:

```
TypeError: this.sourceGuid is not a function
    at Function.Source (http://localhost:8081/js/app/events/model/0-Source.js:14:12)
    at AnalogCamerasSource (http://localhost:8081/js/app/events/model/AnalogCamerasSource.js:3:33)
```

Now, here's a picture from Chrome's debugger showing the properties are there but way down the prototype chain, under `this.__proto__.prototype` when called like `this.__proto__.apply(this, arguments)` from `AnalogCamerasSource`.

[image]

So, why this.sourceGuid is not a function? How should I call the parent's constructor to have this chain working correctly?

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/98bp8pvh/

Comment: inheritance should be like `AnalogCamerasSource.prototype = Object.create(Source.prototype);` or `AnalogCamerasSource.prototype = new Source();`

Comment: Is there are reason not to use es6 classes? You can always transpile to es5 if you need

Comment: @ajaiJothi then I get this error: `TypeError: this.__proto__.apply is not a function
    at AnalogCamerasSource`

Comment: @thedude It must support IE11, and as far as have tested, it works only with Chrome, FIrefox and Edge. It's a big project with already defined systems and build strategies. I'd like to avoid the need to put this in the middle, but definitely possible.

Answer (score 1):

Refactored your code (avoid using `__proto__` in your code)

```js
function Source() {
  var args = arguments[0] || {};
  this._sourceGuid = args.sourceGuid || '';
  this._periodGuid = args.periodGuid || '';
  this._eventName = args.eventName || '';
  this._eventKind = args.eventKind || 0;
};

Source.prototype.sourceGuid = function(value) {
  if (arguments.length > 0) {
    this._sourceGuid = value || '';
  } else {
    return this._sourceGuid;
  }
};

Source.prototype.periodGuid = function(value) {
  if (arguments.length > 0) {
    this._periodGuid = value || '';
  } else {
    return this._periodGuid;
  }
};

Source.prototype.eventName = function(value) {
  if (arguments.length > 0) {
    this._eventName = value || '';
  } else {
    return this._eventName;
  }
};

Source.prototype.eventKind = function(value) {
  if (arguments.length > 0) {
    this._eventKind = value || 0;
  } else {
    return this._eventKind;
  }
};

Source.prototype.toJSON = function() {
  return {
    sourceGuid: this.sourceGuid(),
    periodGuid: this.periodGuid(),
    eventName: this.eventName(),
    eventKind: this.eventKind()
  };
};

function AnalogCamerasSource() {
  var args = arguments[0] || {};
  this._serverGuid = args.serverGuid || '';
  this._cameraId = args.cameraId || 0;
  this._waitingTime = args.waitingTime || 0;
  
  this.sourceGuid(args.sourceGuid);
  this.periodGuid(args.periodGuid);
  this.eventName(args.eventName);
  this.eventKind(args.eventKind);
};

AnalogCamerasSource.prototype = Object.create(Source.prototype);

AnalogCamerasSource.prototype.serverGuid = function(value) {
  if (arguments.length > 0) {
    this._serverGuid = value || '';
  } else {
    return this._serverGuid;
  }
};

AnalogCamerasSource.prototype.cameraId = function(value) {
  if (arguments.length > 0) {
    this._cameraId = value || 0;
  } else {
    return this._cameraId;
  }
};

AnalogCamerasSource.prototype.waitingTime = function(value) {
  if (arguments.length > 0) {
    this._waitingTime = value || 0;
  } else {
    return this._waitingTime;
  }
};

AnalogCamerasSource.prototype.toJSON = function() {
  var json = Source.prototype.toJSON.call(this);

  json.serverGuid = this.serverGuid();
  json.cameraId = this.cameraId();
  json.waitingTime = this.waitingTime();

  return json;
};

var data = {
  "sourceGuid": "{05A00E05-F30D-497D-A272-156F135E1486}",
  "periodGuid": "{8A071454-B473-4937-9C54-4899F866D7FA}",
  "eventName": "signal-lost",
  "eventKind": 3,
  "serverGuid": "{9976B57D-486B-4BCA-8432-78D7C8EDB52B}",
  "cameraId": 4,
  "waitingTime": 5
};

var c = new AnalogCamerasSource(data);
console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with this workaround:

I changed the prototype definition:

```
AnalogCamerasSource.prototype = new Source();
```

Then I added the following function to `AnalogCamerasSource`:

```
AnalogCamerasSource.prototype.super = function() {
  Source.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

And then in the constructor I am calling it as:

```
function AnalogCamerasSource() {
  this.super.apply(this, arguments);
  ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple, do your inheritance like this:

```
AnalogCamerasSource.prototype = Source.prototype;
```

...and just `apply` the constructor function of the parent class in the constructor of the subclass:

```
function AnalogCamerasSource() {
  Source.apply(this, arguments);
  ...
}
```

There usually isn't any need to reference `__proto__` directly.

Comment: Basically the same solution as yours :)

The only problem with this approach:

    AnalogCamerasSource.prototype = new Source();

Is that you have to actually call the constructor function to set up the inheritance, which isn't necessary and wouldn't be possible at this point if the constructor takes arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `AnalogCamerasSource.prototype = Source;` to `AnalogCamerasSource.prototype = new Source;` and `this.__proto__.apply(this, arguments);` to `Source.apply(this, arguments);`.

The problem is that with your approach `AnalogCameraSource.prototype` gets set to a *function* (constructor for Source object), rather than to an object. This function itself does not have the methods defined on its prototype. If you set `AnalogCameraSource.prototype` to a new Source object (created with `new Source`), then `AnalogCameraSource.prototype` is an *object*, which is how things ought to be. This puts all methods defined on the Source prototype in the prototype chain of AnalogCameraSource, and the Source constructor is able to run without a hitch.